# Do I need to update every C# SQL query on a certain table after adding a new nullable column?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, backend, legacy

I work on a legacy product with a .NET C# backend that uses no ORM for reading/updating our db. Queries are written in C# calling on the .NET SQL client with straight up SQL written like:

```
var query = "INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, column3)" +
             "VALUES (@value1, @value2, @value3)" ;
```

I have to add a new nullable column to a table, and will be including that column with a value in a couple of queries. It is a bit value that is null by default.

Do I have to update every query that calls on that table to include the new column? Or am I safe to only add it where needed?

Comment: Because it is nullable, you can omit it.

Comment: From the [`INSERT` TSQL docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "If a column is not in *column_list*, the Database Engine must be able to provide a value based on the definition of the column [...] if the column: [...] Has a default. The default value for the column is used. [...] Is nullable. A null value is used."

Comment: Beware of `SELECT *` queries, they will return the extra column. Also you should use `sp_recompile` on all views and procedures that reference the table

Answer (score 0):

Since the new column has a default value, that value will always be used when inserting even if the new column is not used in the query.

You're safe basically. Using straight ADO.Net gives you a big advantage basically, not only in terms of speed but also common sense. Some ORMs fall over  in this scenario

Comment: *Some ORMs fall over in this scenario* - have you got an example?